# File lock despite using Using

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

```
        try
        {
            using (var input = await client.GetStreamAsync(url))
            using (var file = File.Create(path))
                await input.CopyToAsync(file, token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)//streaming error or cancelation. Anyway we delete the temporary file
        {
            if (File.Exists(path)) File.Delete(path);
            throw;
        }
```

My problem is with the code above. When trying to delete the file it sometimes throws an IO Exception saying that the file is locked for write.

It's on Xamarin Android, is it specific to that platform or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You dont know the cause of the exception... in your scenario, the file CAN  be locked! there's no warranty that in a catch, the file has been released.
I recommand that you add a try... catch around your File.Delete, to avoid error. 
And be sure that every scenario where you need this file, be sure that the file exist or not. 
NEVER TRUST IO.

Comment: your file only gets delete in case of an exception?

Comment: @TheDudeWithHat Yes the file isn't even accesse by anything until the end of the function. Unless it's the os/antivirus but it shouldn't acquire a write lock

Comment: Do you get this on the phone or emulator?

Comment: Also where is this being stored cache directory or app data. This is an extremely strange pattern to use.

Comment: @FilipCordas it is stored on the cache folder of the application. The exception is raised on a device

Comment: Can you open DDMS, then get the emulator root permission, open the file path, check the permission about this file in Linux. Here is a link about linux permission:https://www.droidviews.com/how-to-setfix-file-permissions-on-android-devices-a-beginners-guide/